# How to communicate with one thread from main ui thread (or any other thread)?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, ui-thread

I'm newly working with android `Thread`.

I have a thread Running:

```
private Thread startQuery(){
    return new Thread(() -> {

        Handler handler = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
        for(int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_QUERY && isThreadAlive; i++){

            int tempTime = timePerQuery;

            int finalI = i;
            handler.post(() -> {
                Random random = new Random();
                int num1 = Math.abs(random.nextInt(maxNumb1)), num2 = Math.abs(random.nextInt(maxNumb2));
                setCurrentResult(num1, num2);
                String strNum1 = num1 + "", strNum2 = num2 + "";
                txtOp.setText(typeOfOperation);
                txtNumbers.setText(equalizeNumbers(strNum1, strNum2));
                queryCount = finalI;
                String count = "Query No: " + queryCount;
                txtQueryCount.setText(count);
            });

            while (tempTime > 0 && isThreadAlive){
                int sec = tempTime/1000,
                        min = sec/60;
                int sec1 = sec%60;
                String s = min + " : " + sec1;
                txtRemainingTime.setText(s);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                tempTime -= 1000;
            }
        }


    });

}
```

This thread is making values for variable "currentResult" in each iteration. Now
I want to use the value of "currentResult" from `Main Thread` on Clicking a button like this:

```
if(id == R.id.game_btnSubmit){
        String strInput = edtUserResultInput.getText().toString();
        if(strInput.isEmpty()){
            edtUserResultInput.setError("Enter Result");
            edtUserResultInput.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        double input = Double.parseDouble(strInput);
        if(currentResult == input){
            isRight[queryCount] = 1;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            isRight[queryCount] = 0;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

But the problem is, after clicking the button My app gets freeze.
Why?
Where is the problem or what is the solution?
I'm stuck with this.

Thank you <3

Comment: The code you shared for your main thread doesn't contain any wait, sleep or looping functions. There is nothing that can block the thread, apart from some corner cases with synchronized methods or volatile variables. If this is the case, please also share those methods. Also, I assume the main thread of your application freezes, please verify. Tip: you can use a debugger or profiler to determine where a thread freezes. It would make our job much easier

Comment: do you mean that you want to update your ui from inside the thread right ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want.
@takieddine

Comment: No!
I didn't use any of the method you mentioned.
Actually I have no Idea about those method/functions. 
Can you explain please?
@tibetiroka

Comment: okey you can use this method to use your code on mainthread  runOnUiThread { here }